# ASP.NET: Using head.js in Master Page, ResolveUrl

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, vb.net

I'm trying to use head.js in my master page, and unfortunately -- I can't seem to get the syntax down as I need to use ResolveUrl.

Here's what I have:

```
head.js("<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js") %>","<%= 
ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery.jstree.min.js") %>");
```

Any suggestions? This doesn't work.

By "doesn't work", I mean that the head.js call doesn't recognize the quotations I'm using. It isn't loading the files basically because I have some sort of incorrect syntax that the VS 2010 isn't telling me.

Comment: Could you be more descriptive about "doesn't work"? Does it give you an error message? Produce a path that isn't correct?

Comment: Dumb question, but are you sure the page language is set to C#?

Comment: This is VB.net. And this statement actually works: <link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>css/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: It will work for style sheets but not scripts. To register scripts you have to do it in the Page_Load of the master file: Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("_FoobarScripts", ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/FoobarScripts.js"));

Comment: as an aside, why not use a CDN? No resolving issues there. <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: CDNs are foreign to higher powers, thus we've never been given the go ahead on them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved it.  I had a piece of code loading in the prerender, thus causing an error because the the jQuery file wasn't loading yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it with the ResolveClientUrl helper instead:

```
head.js('<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js") %>','<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/js/jquery.jstree.min.js") %>');
```

Comment: Tried this, but gave me an error that resembled it not loading the JQuery file.

Comment: Makes sense as the helpers do not work in scripts. You can register a startup script in the code behind to set a var with the resolved script file.